# access tortoisesvn repository in wireless network

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using windows 7  and install `tortoisesvn`.
I create repository in `F:\working_direcoty\test-rep` , We have wirless network ,
I set my IP  to 192.168.1.200 ,
how can I access my repository in another computer in local wireless network?
in that system also installed `windowns 7` and `tortoisesvn`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [Subversion server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html), preferably on a server that's online all the time. Do not access a repository over a network connection in the same way that you would if it was on your local hard drive (`file:///` URL).

Once you have a server configured, neither the server nor the client know or care whether you're on a wired or wireless connection.

There are several links listed under "related" on the right side here which discuss this.

Comment: before I use svntortoise without anything else, but I forgot how config it.  only with svntortoise

Comment: Once you leave a single-user, single-computer usage model, you need to run a proper server. The link I provided is the official manual's instructions on doing so. There is good information in the links to the right as well.

Comment: it is full documentation, please tell me how can I  access repository in another computer in local windows wireless network,

Comment: Do you have a server configured yet? If not, you shouldn't be accessing the repository remotely yet. Set up the server first.

Comment: but I remember we work with svntortoise without any subversion server

Comment: As I said previously, you need to have a Subversion server once you move past a single-user, single-computer scenario if you want to do things properly and safely. Saying "but we used to" doesn't change that. Unless you *want* to take unnecessary risks with the integrity of your source code repository - and no one I know accepts those risks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **windows file sharing function** to allow access to the repository (Right click on repository folder -> properties -> sharing). Url tor repository starts with `file:///your_path`

For very small projects we do it in a similar way via network drives. But using a svn-server like alroc mentioned is better way.

Comment: I share it , how can access it in another computer `svn ://192.168.1.200/working_directory/test-rep` failed !!!

Comment: This method is a very bad idea. It can lead to irrecoverable repository corruption and /or data loss up to and including the whole repository.

Comment: @zhilevan: same way you would access the path with explorer. Path in explorer is path to repository.

Comment: @alroc: Question is not if or if not is a bad idea. Of course a server would be better but this is not the point of the question. If you use svn-clients you will not get in trouble.

Comment: @zhilevan: my url starts like: file:///your_path

Comment: Yes, you *will* get in trouble using a `file:///` URL - one errant press of the Delete key in Explorer and your repository is corrupted/lost. Assuming that you don't run into filesystem-level permissions problems first. While it may *technically* be possible to do it, IMHO actions which the developers of the software explicitly discourage  and could lead to data loss shouldn't be suggested as "solutions" to someone trying to figure out how to use the software properly.

Comment: @alroc: Yes, there for server is better solution no doubt about this fact, but we practice this in 2-3 person projects and it work fine. Of course there are some organizational-rules to follow ... like everywhere. So redo downvote (if it comes from you) would be nice, because I answer the question and don't want to challenge the proceeding.

Comment: "It works for me" is not a valid defense against working counter to accepted best practices IMO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48883/discussion-between-micha-and-alroc)

Comment: @zhilevan: was additional **file:///** info helpful?